# Minimum number of triggers and actions to publish a zapier app?

Tags: zapier

I worked with Zapier a few years ago and remember that they expect a minimum number of triggers and actions to go live on the app directory. However I'm not finding that document right now (or maybe it was never there and I'm mistaken?).

Does anyone have context on what's the least number of triggers and actions needed to go live with a Zapier app?

Answer (score 0):

There's no hard and fast rule here. 1 is the minimum. Initially it's recommended to do no more than 5 total. From [the docs](https://platform.zapier.com/partners/lifecycle-planning#1-ensure-your-integration-follows-the-zapier-integration-development-guide):

> We recommend your Zapier integration have no more than 5 of each (trigger, action, or search) at first; we suggest starting with your most popular 2-3 use cases.

You shouldn't pad your integration; it should have enough important functionality to be useful.